# Run PHP Composer Commands from Client to Server

Tags: php, windows, networking, server, composer-php

We have a php project shared on a server on our local network. Developers are working on the same project using the client pcs. Now we need to run the composer commands on the main project without giving them access to our main server. Is it possible to run php composer commands from local client to local server?

Comment: do you have `composer` in path variable in your server pc?

Comment: yes, we do have composer installed on our server as well as on our client pc both

Comment: I'm pretty unclear about the exact scenario here. You have a network share with PHP files on it and multiple people are editing those files at the same time…?

Comment: yes.. but each one is working on its specific file.

Comment: What about using a sane collaboration system like git…?

Answer (score 0):

First off all **do not let clients to access composer by any means** as the can upload a shell directly to your server and all of your hosted domains can be hacked.

Let's guess you have no problem with this issue,

1. you have to be confirm that composer is accessible from command line directly.
   `composer ** **` like this
2. use `exec`, `shell_exec` etc  command from any php script directly.
3. Be sure that all of your  clients have permission to access composer (if you are in linux)

**Note: It is a very bad practice to let them get access to composer. Your server may be compromised.**